# Diagonalizing a nearly-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, diagonalization

Take a (kind of) arrowhead real-symmetric matrix of the general form

$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} & a_{16} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} & a_{26} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{14} & a_{24} & 0 & a_{44} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{15} & a_{25} & 0 & 0 & a_{55} & 0 \\
a_{16} & a_{26} & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{66} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where the size of the blocks may vary, however in general, the diagonal submatrix will be of dimension close to that of the entire matrix. Is there a method to diagonalise this matrix which takes advantage of this largely diagonal structure? My desire is computational efficiency, i.e. compared to `dgemm`.

I require all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix, i.e. $V^{-1}MV = W$ where $V$ are the eigenvectors of $M$, and $W$ a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues.

Comment: well, do you mean $P^{-1}AP = D_1$ where you will need the eigenvalues, or do you mean $W^T A W = D_2 \; , \; $ with nonsingular $W \;, \;$ which is the correct change of variables for quadratic forms? The latter equivalence relation is often called congruence.

Comment: @WillJagy I mean your first statement - I require the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, which I should have stated (I will update the question)

Comment: Is the length of the "non-diagonal" block always 2?

Comment: @user3257842 no, however it is always smaller (typically much smaller) than the length of the diagonal block

Comment: This looks like something expressible as a low-rank update of a diagonal matrix. There are methods for solving low-rank modified eigen-problems, see, e.g., [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/143555/40734) @ MO.

Answer (score 2):

One way of levering this structure to gain efficiency is by noticing that if the diagonal block is large compared to the rest, then you gain save a lot of time by using Krylov methods, as the matrix-vector product can be computed quite fast, and the full matrix need not be stored in memory. The simplest version of this is probably the [Arnoldi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration), which a lot of computing environments do under the hood. To my knowledge, both MATLAB's "eigs" and Scipy's "sparse.linalg.eigs" are wrappers for a version of the Arnoldi algorithm found in [ARPACK](https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/), although I do not know any more details.